# how to make the whole downstream flow of an executor-channel task retry-able?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In the same way as you can easily add an advice to a poller (for a queue-channel) so as to apply it to the entire downstream flow, is there a way to make the whole downstream flow of an executor-channel task retry-able ?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a `HandleMessageAdvice` with a `RetryTemplate` and add it to the first component's advice chain.